# Why div element that on show mobile browser difference show on desktop?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive

Why div element that on show mobile browser difference show on desktop ?

```
<html>
    <body style=" margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; ">
        <div style=" width: 1263px; position: fixed; height: 60px; background: red; "></div>
        <div style=" width: 1263px; background: blue; height: 500px; ">
            <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png" style=" width: 1263px; "/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Show on ie mobile and opera mini

[image]

Show on desktop (google chrome)

[image]

Why red bar div on mobile shorten ?

How can i do ?

Comment: change the width to 100%

Comment: why i can not use px ?

Comment: because each browser and device has its own resolution.

Comment: When i change to width: 120% , div red bar still short

Comment: zooming in a bit does change the red bar to the full width. Interesting.

Comment: @Pete Why would two elements with the same width in pixels have different widths on the screen, even if it was a mobile device? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MrLister haha, didn't see that, and then I was going to suggest that the image inside may have stretched the blue container but that is the same size too.  My last guess would be due to the fixed position and no left or right value, perhaps it has started minus left?  Try adding `left:0;` to the red bar